# Why is my div component always rendering with text, regardless of the context?

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm trying to unrender a div component when my function returns false, but it is not working properly, though it is working on the input. I need help finding out what causes this problem, that it is always rendering the red div with text, no matter what the context is.

```
boletoVenceHoje(): boolean {
    if (this.dataAtual.getMonth() === this.maxDate.getMonth() && this.dataAtual.getDay() === this.maxDate.getDay() && this.dataAtual.getFullYear() === this.maxDate.getFullYear()) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false   
    }
}
```

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0">
    <input *ngIf="isAgendamento" nbInput placeholder="Seleciona a Data" [nbDatepicker]="data" [(ngModel)]="dataAgendamento" [disabled]="!boletoVenceHoje" />
    <div *ngIf="isAgendamento && boletoVenceHoje" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-left: 10px">
        <p style="color: red; float: right; margin-left: 10px">
            Boletos vencidos não podem ser agendados.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried changing the function and the properties

Comment: do you have stackblitz example?

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the `boletoVenceHoje` function in your `*ngIf` so you're not evaluating the return value. Add parentheses e.g -

```html
<div *ngIf="isAgendamento && boletoVenceHoje()" ...>
```

If `isAgendamento` is also a function you'll have to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Angular but searching Angular examples, I didn't see a condition with 'and' operator. Maybe it is not possible there but you can create a function outside in order to validate all conditions (remove boletoVenceHoja):

```js
const isComponentValid() => {
  return isAgendamento && this.dataAtual.getMonth() === this.maxDate.getMonth() && this.dataAtual.getDay() === this.maxDate.getDay() && this.dataAtual.getFullYear() === this.maxDate.getFullYear()
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="isComponentValid" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-left: 10px">
        <p style="color: red; float: right; margin-left: 10px">
            Boletos vencidos não podem ser agendados.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because You called the function as variable. It should be like that

`[disabled]="!boletoVenceHoje()"`